# Power BI weekly rolling average using Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, rolling-average

In Power BI, I have 4 columns - date year, week no, and the respective week's sales.

```
    date         Year    Week No.    Sales
   Jan-1-2022    2022    1           100
   Jan-9-2022    2022    2           200
   Jan-17-2023   2023    3           300
```

Now I want to create a rolling average (moving average) for 4 weeks. I tried writing the following measure, but it's not giving me the proper result.

```
RollingAvg = 
var numDays = 28
var lastselectedDate = MAX('data'[date])
var period = DATESINPERIOD('data'[date], lastselectedDate, -numDays, DAY)
var result = CALCULATE(
        AVERAGEX(VALUES('data'[sales]),
'data'[sales]


),
period

)
return

result
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.